# ¿Cómo usar en un Select los valores que agregue en el LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, select, local-storage, options

quisiera saber como tomar con un Select los valores que agregue en el LocalStorage, y que este Select despliegue esos valores adiquiridos

Esto es el html donde basicamente quiero que ese Select tome los valores del LocalStorage y cree Options al cargar la pagina.

```
   <main>
            <h2>El Clima Ahora</h2>
            <section id="form-city-list">
                <form id="form">
                    <select name="city" id="city" onload="cargarDatos()">
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Seleccionar ciudad</option>
                    </select>
                    <button id="consult">Consultar</button>
                </form>
            </section>
```

Esto es en el js. Es una funcion que encontre para cargar datos desde el LocalStorage pero no me funciona.

```
    function cargarDatos(){
        let cities = localStorage.getItem("CITIES");
            if (cities) {
                cities = JSON.parse(cities);
            } else {
                cities = [];
            }
            return cities;
    }
```

Comment: ¿En qué formato estás guardando las ciudades y qué quieres mostrar? Tu código actual sólo hace un parse, pero nada más y el `if ... else` no tiene sentido.

Comment: `cities` no es un booleano.

Answer (score 0):

Desde tu función, tendrías crear los `option` que resultasen de la lectura de las ciudades almacenadas y asignarlos al `select`, alcazándolo por su `id`.

Imaginemos que almacenas las ciudades como objetos, con dos propiedades, `id` y `name`, puedes poner algo así en tu función:

[<kbd>**`VER DEMO`**</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/acedano/oLsh48zd/17/)

```
let allCities = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cities"));
if (allCities !== null) {
  const fragment = new DocumentFragment();
  const selCity = document.getElementById('city');
  for (const city of allCities) {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = city.id;
    option.textContent = city.name;
    fragment.append(option);
  }
  selCity.append(fragment);
}
```

Imaginemos que tus ciudades son un elemento simple, la función podría quedar así:

[<kbd>**`VER DEMO`**</kbd>](https://jsfiddle.net/acedano/e2jwdpsa/11/)

```
let allCities = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("CITIES"));

if (allCities !== null) {
  const fragment = new DocumentFragment();
  const selCity = document.getElementById('city');
  for (const city of allCities) {
    const option = document.createElement('option');
    option.value = city;
    option.textContent = city;
    fragment.append(option);
  }
  selCity.append(fragment);
}
```

#### PD

Nótese que hemos usado un fragmento, para hacer append de cada `option` y sólo al final del bucle hacemos append de ese fragmento en el `select`. Esta es la práctica recomendada cuando modificamos elementos en bucle, porque si haces append directamente en cada iteracción, el DOM se renderizará en cada append. Hemos usado también `createElement` porque es el modo más seguro de crear elementos dinámicos, evitando posibles ataques XSS.